# Bootstrap integration into a php website

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal, paytm

I am a beginner in PHP. I have tried developing a website in PHP through tutorials but no I am struck with a problem.

The problem is how can I integrate bootstrap into my website so that it can be compatible through other devices like phones and tablets and also how to integrate paytm into my payment page ?

Comment: What specific problem do you have? What have you tried already?

Comment: Actually I want my website to be compatible with any type of device like smartphones and tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Check here :
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Call all bootstrap files in a php file, and include this file in all your pages.

If you have good skills in PHP, you should create templates. Some informations:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/getting-started-with-php-templating/